# Tool-tip with scroll. Scroll is disappearing when mouse hover on arrows.

Tags: html, css, scroll, tooltip, mousehover

Hi the tooltip in this sniped closes when trying to hover on the arrows of the scroll. With the mouse scroll it works fine but i need it to work with mousehover.
Got any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

```css
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip {
    transform: none;
    margin: 50px;    
}

.tooltip:hover > .tooltip-text, .tooltip:hover > .wrapper {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.tooltip > .tooltip-text, .tooltip >.wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6000;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.0;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

/* Arrow */
.tooltip > .tooltip-text:before, .tooltip > .wrapper:before  {
    display: inline;
    top: -5px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) transparent;
    border-width: 0 .5em .5em .5em;
    z-index: 6000;
    left: 20px;
}

/* Invisible area so you can hover over tooltip */
.tooltip > .tooltip-text:after, .tooltip > .wrapper:after  {
    top: -20px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    left: 20px;
}

.wrapper > .tooltip-text {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip tooltip-scroll">Hover over me for scrollbar
    <div class="wrapper"> 
    <span class="tooltip-text">Hello there<br/>Hello there<br/>Hello there<br/>Hello there<br/>Hello there<br/>Hello there<br/>abc<br/>def<br/><br/>def<br/><br/>def<br/><br/>def<br/>ghi<br/>jkl<br/></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox. Which OS / Browser are you using?

Comment: Hi, im using chrome, this bug is only happening on chrome

Answer (score 0):

based on my try-error research, I got a solution for webkit based on applying styles to "force" the browser to handle the scrollbar as another page element:

```css
.tooltip.tooltip-scroll ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.tooltip.tooltip-scroll ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #C1C1C1;
    border: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

/* optional */
.tooltip.tooltip-scroll ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
```

(More examples on how to style the scrollbar [@CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).)

Also, here goes an extra help.
Change style **.tooltip** for this:

```css
.tooltip {
    transform: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The padding allows the element that triggers the tooltip to do not lose the **:hover** state when moving the mouse pointer from the element to the tooltip. Since the padding area is still considered part of the element.

Note for Stack Overflow community: please, feel free to provide extra information on how this works.